# COS: Google Container-Optimized OS: How do I record process CPU usage over time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-os

I have a VM running Google Container-Optimized OS (COS).

It has been running fine for 6 weeks, then suddenly yesterday CPU spiked to 100% for 12 hours, and disk read IOP/Throughput also stayed high during this time.

What can I run on the VM to record exactly which process is causing this?

Because COS is locked down, it seems I cannot install `psacct`.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

See [Debugging node issues using toolbox](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/toolbox)

> Although Container-Optimized OS does not include a package manager,
> you can use the pre-installed toolbox utility to install any
> additional packages or tools you require. Using /usr/bin/toolbox is
> the preferred method for installing and running one-off debugging
> tools.
>
> Once you've invoked the toolbox utility to start the shell, you can
> use apt-get inside the resulting container to install packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [Node Problem Detector agent](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/monitoring) to monitor the system health of COS instances

You can check [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-compute) the list of supported Disk, Throughput and CPU metrics, Do note that some of the metrics are still on Alpha and Beta phase

Comment: It does not seem to track process names. I know the CPU is high, but not why.